# bootstrap - add horiztonal space beetwen two buttons with float right

Tags: css, button, space

I would like to have 2 buttons on the right side in a form, but when I put them they have no space between them

I have this

```
  <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
       <button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button">
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></iAdd place
       </button>
      <button id="btn-add-file" class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button">
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload CSV
      </button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the result[image]

Comment: Such floated elements don't have margins applied. Add margin or padding manually to detach them

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, you may just add class `ml-1` (or `ml-2` etc) to the "Add Place" button. something like:

```
<button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary float-right ml-1" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add place
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a right margin to the first button or a left margin to the second button. This can be done in CSS or using a [Bootstrap spacing utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/).